# Zooming an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, zooming, android-view, gestures

So I have spent a number of hours searching the web for help but all forums and documentation has not properly explained to me the best way I should go about this.

Currently I have an activity with an XML relative layout (the background is set to a picture of a map) and I would like to implement a multi-gesture zoom feature. After a lot of reading it seems that I should be using ScrollGestureDetector which must be implemented inside a view.

I would like to make it so that the user can use a 2 pointer gesture anywhere on the screen and it will zoom in. The issue is that I don't know how to implement this and cannot find resources to show me how to do this to an activity.

Is there any way I can implement ScrollGestureDetector for my RelativeLayout? Should I create a custom view that covers the entire screen and presents the picture so that I can implement ScrollGestureDetector in the class definition? How should I go about this?

Comment: You can use this tutorial to implement it : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_gestures.htm

Comment: The issue is that I already have a Activity.setOnTouchListener() set up for a number of different touch locations. How can I combine these two solutions? Or is it the case that I will have to handle all touches through ScrollGestureDetector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pinch-zoom to scale an image works best if the image is within an `ImageView`.   The `ImageView` can scale images arbitrarily while background images are scaled based only on the view bounds.

You just need to call `setContentView()` on your activity with a layout that contains an `ImageView`.

To use ScaleGestureDetector in your code, you have to do the following

1. Declare a ScaleGestureDetector in your view.

   ```
   private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
   ```
2. Initialize it with your scaling event listener, preferable in `onCreate()`:

   ```
   mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
           // your impl here
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
           // your impl here
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
           // your impl here
       }
   })
   ```
3. Add the ScaleGestureDetector to your `onTouchEvent()` method:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

       mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

       // do other stuff
       return super.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
   ```

Strangely, `ScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent()` *always* returns true, but you can use `isInProgress()` to tell if a scaling operation has started.

Comment: Is there no way I can implement ScaleGestureDetector inside my existing Activity.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      //do something
      return true
   }
});

Comment: Thank you. I am confused about whether number 2 and 3 are implemented inside view or activity

Comment: It depends.  In your question you mentioned creating a custom view, which is a good choice.  If it's a view that doesn't have any touch behavior to speak of, you can just set an `OnTouchListener` which would have the `onTouchEvent` implementation.  In other words, you have code in your activity that calls `view.setOnTouchListener()`   The activity can also listen for touch events, which is what you have set up.  If you're scaling the entire screen, that's a valid strategy, too.